# I want to map json object nested inside another object to POJO using jackson library

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have an object nested inside another object in Json file. I want to map this object with fields to a Model class.

```
{
"code": 200,
"time": "2019-09-05T07:09:44.228+0000",
"data": {
    "statuses": [
        {
            "statusType": "IN_PROGRESS",
            "statusTimestamp":"019-09-05T17:04:54+1000"
        },
        {
            "statusType": "SENT",
            "statusTimestamp":"2019-09-05T21:04:55+1000"
        },
        {
            "statusType": "OPENED",
            "statusTimestamp":"2019-09-05T23:04:55+1000"
        },
        {
            "statusType": "INTERACTION_ID_RECEIVED",
            "statusTimestamp":"2019-09-06T00:04:55+1000"
        }
    ]
},
"status": 200,
"message": null,
"errors": null,
}
```

I want to map the statusType and TimeStamp to a custom model class.

Model Class:

public class Model{

```
private String statusType;
private DateTime statusTimestamp;

public Model(String statusType, String statusTimestamp) {
    this.statusType=statusType;
    this.statusTimestamp=new DateTime(statusTimestamp);
}
public String getStatusType() {
    return statusType;
}

public void setStatusType(String statusType) {
    this.statusType = statusType;
}

public DateTime getStatusTimestamp() {
    return statusTimestamp;
}

public void setStatusTimestamp(String statusTimestamp) {
    this.statusTimestamp = new DateTime(statusTimestamp);
}
```

}

I want to map the statuses to this model class and store these objects in a link something like this

List statuses = ParsedJson.read("$..['statuses'][*]", List.class)

Comment: show the custom model class.

Comment: Quite useful tool: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @Deadpool Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to model the entire response, you could use Jackson to parse the JSON into tree nodes and then map only the parts you care about:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
JsonNode statusesNode = rootNode.path("data").path("statuses");
List<Status> statuses = mapper.convertValue(statusesNode,
    new TypeReference<List<Status>>(){});
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I was able to map the using convertValue.

Answer (score 0):

I saw 2 errors in the json string fixing it should help you to create Object using java or any other language easily.

line 12: " was missing
line 26: invalid placement of ,

Json after fixing issues

```
{
"code": 200,
"time": "2019-09-05T07:09:44.228+0000",
"data": {
    "statuses": [
        {
            "statusType": "IN_PROGRESS",
            "statusTimestamp":"019-09-05T17:04:54+1000"
        },
        {
            "statusType": "SENT",
            "statusTimestamp":"2019-09-05T21:04:55+1000"
        },
        {
            "statusType": "OPENED",
        "statusTimestamp":"2019-09-05T23:04:55+1000"
        },
        {
            "statusType": "INTERACTION_ID_RECEIVED",
        "statusTimestamp":"2019-09-06T00:04:55+1000"
        }
    ]
},
"status": 200,
"message": null,
"errors": null
}
```